# authblk affiliations on same line

Tags: titles, authblk

When using authblk and an author/affilliation list like this:

```
\author[1]{Auth1}
\author[1]{Auth2}
\author[1]{Auth3}
\author[1]{Auth4}
\author[2]{Auth5}
\author[1]{Auth6}
\author[2]{Auth7}

\affil[1]{Affil1}
\affil[2]{Affil2}
```

The affilliations each show up on their own line:

```
1 Affil1
2 Affil2
```

How can I get them on the same line?

```
1 Affil1   2 Affil2
```

Answer (score 9):

```
\usepackage{authblk}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\AB@affilsepx{ --- \protect\Affilfont}
\makeatother
```

In this way the affiliations will separated by an em-dash surrounded by spaces. Choose what suits you.