# How can I make a LaTeX poster with all affiliations on the same line, using Beamer?

Tags: beamer, titles

I'm using the `beamer` class and all the examples I can find have the author affiliations on different lines. My research project requires us to have them all on 1 line, with superscripts indicating the author's correct affiliation. Here is my current code.

```
\title{Title goes here} 
\author[shortname]{Author1 \inst{1} \and Author2 \inst{2}     \and Author3     \inst{3}}
\institute[shortinst]{\inst{1} Affil1 \and 
                  \inst{2} Afil2 \and \inst{3} Afil3 }
```

For the record, I tried reading [authblk affiliations on same line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30394/authblk-affiliations-on-same-line) but didn't understand it. Simple examples are needed with my knowledge level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer), the institute `\and` is defined as

```
\def\beamer@andinst{\\[1em]}
```

so that it inserts a line break and leaves a 1em *vertical* gap between entries. Mere redefine this as

```
\makeatletter
\def\beamer@andinst{\quad}
\makeatother
```

to insert a 1em *horizontal* gap between entries:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Title goes here}
\author[shortname]{Author1 \inst{1} \and Author2 \inst{2} \and Author3 \inst{3}}
\institute[shortinst]{\inst{1} Affil1 \and \inst{2} Affil2 \and \inst{3} Affil3}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@andinst{\quad}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful! Now I'm dealing with an issue with it listing the affiliations on two separate lines, with a line break, as opposed to each going on separate ones.  Is there a painless way to force them to be on the same line? (my job requires us to follow a powerpoint example for a poster, and I'd prefer to use LaTeX)

Comment: @user56365: I don't really understand your question. Are you saying that the affiliations have multiple entries, and they should be stacked? Could you provide more detail?

Comment: The affiliations need to be all on one line, with no line breaks whatsoever. Your initial advice prevents the affiliations from each being in separate stacked columns, but it does not prevent there from being any line breaks, and the 3 affiliations end up on 2 lines(they are kinda long, but do not take up the entire poster width), with a break in the middle of the second affiliation.

Comment: @user56365: You could attempt to use `\institute[shortinst]{\makebox[0pt]{...}}`. Let me know...

Comment: Thanks a ton, it looks perfect now! I'm far from a LaTeX expert, and I very much appreciate your help!