# beamer: display affiliations in one paragraph (comma separated)

Tags: beamer, author, affiliation

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\author{auth1 \inst{1} \and auth2 \inst{2} \and auth3 \inst{2} \and auth4 \inst{3}}
\institute[shortinst]{\inst{1} inst1 \and \inst{2} inst2 \and \inst{3} inst3}
\begin{document}
\titlepage
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to keep the list of affiliations in one, comma separated paragraph (to economise space)?

Comment: The solution to [How can I make a LaTeX poster with all affiliations on the same line, using Beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187385/134144) should also work in your case.

Comment: @leandriis, yes it does