# beamer: separate authors by comma, do not linebreak authors

Tags: beamer, author

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\author{name1 surn1 \inst{1} \and name2 surn2 \inst{2} \and name3 surn3 \inst{2} \and name4 surn4 \inst{3}}
\institute[shortinst]{\inst{1} inst1 \and \inst{2} inst2 \and \inst{3} inst3}
\begin{document}
\titlepage
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to separate the authors with a comma? How to avoid a line break between an author name and surname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187397/134144, you could redefine `\beamer@andtitle` to yield a comma instead:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@andtitle{\unskip, } % replaces \and between author names (original definition is \quad)
\def\beamer@andinst{\quad} % replaces \and between institutions (original definition is \\[1em])
\makeatother

\author{name1~surn1\inst{1} \and name2~surn2\inst{2} \and name3~surn3\inst{2} \and name4~surn4\inst{3}}
\institute[shortinst]{\inst{1} inst1 \and \inst{2} inst2 \and \inst{3} inst3}

\begin{document}
\titlepage
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\author{name1~surn1\inst{1}, \and name2~surn2\inst{2}, \and name3~surn3\inst{2}, \and name4~surn4\inst{3}}
\institute[shortinst]{\inst{1} inst1 \and \inst{2} inst2 \and \inst{3} inst3}
\begin{document}
\titlepage
\end{document}
```

[image]

The tilde (`~`) produces a non breaking space.