# affiliations on the same line using authblk (command \renewcommand\AB@affilsepx not working)

Tags: authblk

I was following the solution provided in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30394/authblk-affiliations-on-same-line) to put 3 affiliations on the same line using `authblk` but failed. The author/affiliation list is like:

```
\author[1]{author1}
\author[2]{author2}
\author[3]{author3}
\affil[1]{dept1}
\affil[2]{dept2}
\affil[3]{dept3}
```

Following the answer in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30394/authblk-affiliations-on-same-line), I add these commands:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\AB@affilsepx{, \protect\Affilfont}
\makeatother
```

in order to typeset the affiliations to:

```
1 dept1, 2 dept2, 3 dept3
```

But the result showed still as:

```
1 dept1
2 dept2
3 dept3
```

I didn't set a local repository for `authblk`. I used the online repo hosted and provided by my university. Would this be the reason that the `\renewcommand\AB@affilspex` command not working? Anyone can provide another way to achieve "affiliations on the same line" problem?

Answer (score 11):

May be this will help you,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{authblk}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand\AB@affilsepx{, \protect\Affilfont}
\makeatother

\title{Your Title}
\author[1]{author1}
\author[2]{author2}
\author[3]{author3}
\affil[1]{dept1}
\affil[2]{dept2}
\affil[3]{dept3}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Here is the output,

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I used: ```\makeatletter
\renewcommand\AB@affilsepx{\hfill \protect\Affilfont}
\makeatother```
to use space instead of commas between the affiliations.