# Adding Multiple Authors with Different Affiliation in LaTeX Article

Tags: article, affiliation, author

**Updated:**

I want would like to add more than one author affiliation in latex article. To make this I have tried with the following latex code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\author[1]{A. Author}
\author[2]{B. Author}
\author[3]{C.  Author}
%\author[2]{Corresponding Author\thanks{email@2nduniversity.com}}
\affil[1,2]{Institution of the Authors from  University}
\affil[3]{Institution of the Authors from  College}
\affil[1]{Email id: aa@gmail.com}
\affil[2]{Email id: ba@gmail.com}
\affil[1,3]{Email id: ca@gmail.com}
\title{Title of the Presentation}
\date{}
%
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Main Part of document here.
\end{document}.
```

But it does not give my desired output. I want exactly like this :
[image]
How can I do this?

Comment: You have some mistakes like : 1)not A in first authors name, 2) third author has number one instead of [3]... The only difference in the result after these changes is a blank line after author that can be solved with the "fix" `\author[3]{C.  Author\vspace*{-10pt}}` and that the emails are in separate lines. Do you want the emails in the same line too?

Comment: @koleygr thank you for point out my mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apart from correcting the typo in `\author[1]{C.  Author}`, which should be `\author[3]{C.  Author}` as pointed out in the comments, you can use the approach in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30395/150114) to make the emails appear on the same line. The following code block determines what appears between affiliations (in this case, a comma followed by a space):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\AB@affilsepx{, \protect\Affilfont}
\makeatother
```

To make this change local, you should enclose all the email code in curly braces `{}`. To include the `Email ids:` header, you can use an affiliation whose tag is a space (`\affil[ ]{Email ids}`) and `:` as separator:

```
{
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\AB@affilsepx{: \protect\Affilfont}
    \makeatother

    \affil[ ]{Email ids}

    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\AB@affilsepx{, \protect\Affilfont}
    \makeatother

    \affil[1]{aa@gmail.com}
    \affil[2]{ba@gmail.com}
    \affil[1,3]{ca@gmail.com}
}
```

[image]

The full code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\author[1]{A. Author}
\author[2]{B. Author}
\author[3]{C.  Author}
%\author[2]{Corresponding Author\thanks{email@2nduniversity.com}}
\affil[1,2]{Institution of the Authors from  University}
\affil[3]{Institution of the Authors from  College}
{
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\AB@affilsepx{: \protect\Affilfont}
    \makeatother

    \affil[ ]{Email ids}

    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\AB@affilsepx{, \protect\Affilfont}
    \makeatother

    \affil[1]{aa@gmail.com}
    \affil[2]{ba@gmail.com}
    \affil[1,3]{ca@gmail.com}
}

\title{Title of the Presentation}
\date{}
%
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    Main Part of document here.
\end{document}.
```